# Adding RPLIDAR_ROS as package dependency

Tags: ros, rplidar, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to catkin_make a new package, with the rplidar_ros package as a dependency.  However, when I run catkin_make, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "rplidar_ros/" with
  any of the following names:

    rplidar_ros/Config.cmake
    rplidar_ros/-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "rplidar_ros/" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "rplidar_ros/_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "rplidar_ros/" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ugv_2dnav/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

**System info:**  Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Indigo, rplidar_ros version 1.01

The rplidar_ros package was successfully cloned and catkin_make-d before I attempted to create this new package.  I'm stumped!  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!
Jack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227151/adding-rplidar_ros-as-package-dependency./) by [JSR694](https://answers.ros.org/users/20011/jsr694/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) on 2016-02-20**:
Where did you clone the rplidar package from? Was it the cob_substitute repo listed on the ROS wiki rplidar_ros page, or was it from robopeak? I cloned from the robopeak repo and never had any issues.

**Comment by [JSR694](https://answers.ros.org/users/20011/jsr694/) on 2016-02-25**:
My apologies for the delay in response!  I cloned robopeak's repo.  Again, I could run their demo just fine; problems only arose when trying to make a package with rplidar+ros as a dependency.  The problem was resolved by Akif, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like there is an error with package name.  "`rplidar_ros/`" should be "`rplidar_ros`" (note the trailing slash). Maybe you have a typo.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JSR694](https://answers.ros.org/users/20011/jsr694/) on 2016-02-25**:
Yes, this was the problem!  A silly mistake :.  Thanks for your help!